# Filter product Django "LATEST", "BEST SALE", "TOP RATED","ON SALE"

Tags: django, filter, categories, product

I have 4 categories `LATEST`, `BEST SALE`, `TOP RATED` and `ON SALE`.

- In the `LATEST`, I want to show the 20 most recently added products.
- In the `BEST SALE`, need to show products that have the best-selling status.
- In the `TOP RATED`, need to show 20 products with a high rating.
- In the `ON SALE`, need to show 20 products that have the sale status.

How do I make a filter for these categories? Thanks a lot. Some examples Django, please.

```py
#functions link to path image upload
def user_products_path(instance, filename):
    return 'products/user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.created_by, filename)

class ParentCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=105, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    short_description = CKEditor5Field(_('Short description'), config_name='extends', null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), default='noimage.png', upload_to='admin/menu')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated'), auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Parent Menu')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Parent Menu')

class MenuBarProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=105, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    #parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentMenu, verbose_name=_('Parent menu'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), default='noimage.png', upload_to='admin/menu')
    #short_description = CKEditor5Field(_('Short description'), config_name='extends', null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated'), auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Menu bar')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Menu bar')

class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=105, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), default='noimage.png', upload_to='admin/menu')
    #short_description = CKEditor5Field(_('Short description'), config_name='extends', null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated'), auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Category Menu')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Category Menu')


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=65, blank=True, null=True, default=None, help_text=_('The maximum number of characters - 65'))
    slug = models.CharField(_('ULR'), max_length=65, blank=True, null=True, default=None, help_text=_('This field fill up automatically (URL links of product'))
    short_description = CKEditor5Field(_('Short description'), config_name='extends', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), default='picture.pnp', null=True, upload_to=user_products_path)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True, help_text=_('Activated, allow to publish'))
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated'), auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categories')


class Product(models.Model):
    
    StatusProduct=(
        (_(''), _('')),
        (_('best sale'), _('BEST SALE')),
        (_('on sale'), _('ON SALE')),
    )
    
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, default=None, help_text=_('The maximum number of characters - 150'))
    price = models.DecimalField(_('Price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=1, default=0)
    discount = models.IntegerField(_('Discount'), default=0)
    status = models.CharField(_('Status'), max_length=20, choices=StatusProduct, default='')
    parentcategory = models.ForeignKey(ParentCategory, verbose_name=_('Category'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    category = models.ForeignKey(MenuBarProduct, verbose_name=_('Category'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(CategoryProduct, verbose_name=_('Category'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    short_description = CKEditor5Field(_('Short description'), config_name='extends', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    description = CKEditor5Field(_('Description'),config_name='extends', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True, help_text=_('Activated, allow to publish'))
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated'), auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Product')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Product')


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name=_('Product'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to=user_products_path)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(_('Active main'), default=False, help_text=_('Active to publish main image'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=False, help_text=_('Activated, allow to publish'))
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated'), auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Product Image')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Images of products')
```

Comment: Please add your `Category` model as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter them with:

1. For latest:

   Product.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:20]
2. BEST SALE - you can add a new total_sales fields and order them again:

   Product.objects.all().order_by('-total_sales')[:20]

or you could add it as property:

```
def is_best_sale(self):
    if self.total_sales > 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

3. TOP RATED  -  you should add a field which will store the average rating and a function to calculate the average rating and modify the field. Once set you can again filter as in 1.
4. ON SALE  -  set an on_sale Boolean field which will show if a product is on sale. As you may work with numerous products and numerous on_sales you can set additional field, for example on_sale_start_date/on_sale_end_date and a function to check them and modify the on_sale value